# Recover Context after redraw

Tags: python

Calling `context.area.ui_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'` succeeds before redraw.

After redrawing using `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)` it fails, with the error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ui_type'`

How can I restore the context so that area is not `NoneType` ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to [Override the Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context):

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

# Before calling redraw, create the override dict
override = context.copy()

# After redraw, set the area on the override instead of the context object
override['area'].ui_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

# Pass the overrides as a dictionary to the context manager 
with context.temp_override(**override):
    bpy.ops.image.save_as(filepath = my_filepath)
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

# Before calling redraw, create the override dict
override = context.copy()

# After redraw, set the area on the override instead of the context object
override['area'].ui_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

# Any bpy.ops.* calls must pass the override as the 1st argument eg:
bpy.ops.image.save_as(override, filepath = my_filepath)
```